# What to do if Selenium hangs in Celery tasks and blocks the entire Celery?

Tags: python, selenium, celery

I use Celery, Celery beat, Redis, Python, Selenium In the tasks of the seleri there are calls to various sites through Selenium and getting information from them. Scheduled every minute.

Sometimes the site does not have an element or it does not load or something. As a result, sooner or later, all this leads to Celeri's freezing and the application not working. What should I do and how can I separate each task from the impact on the application? They say if there is a problem or a freeze, the task is killed and this does not in any way affect the operation of the application and the selection.

Tried this https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

The result is getting a little better, but anyway there is a freeze sooner or later and that's it, a server reboot is needed. In the console, I see such an unrealistic execution time of tasks for more than 10 seconds and, as a result, then freezing.

```
 [2021-01-29 20:59:43,903: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.btc_hashrate_vs_price[a79dae51-b5b6-42c3-8653-eb3db594a6d9] succeeded in 285.46829061600147s: None
[2021-01-29 20:59:45,813: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.btc_rsi[f2395a63-885e-4339-954e-f5aa7b7488c3]  
[2021-01-29 21:04:13,102: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

[2021-01-29 21:04:15,840: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.btc_predict_cycle[11eb2199-0445-4fea-9916-d303a2a93643] succeeded in 271.53123419199255s: None
[2021-01-29 21:07:28,399: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.fear_greed_index[4ecb533e-c758-4c47-b1bc-2ba13e475861]  
[2021-01-29 21:08:44,493: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver

[2021-01-29 21:08:46,465: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.btc_gold[63bb0013-f2c8-4876-9aa8-ca14ec1e8ebd] succeeded in 119.68898677200195s: None
[2021-01-29 21:09:06,504: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.btc_liquidation_exchanges[4286d9b4-4434-4149-8443-c7370a66e587]  
[2021-01-29 21:12:41,417: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Message: chrome not reachable

[2021-01-29 21:12:41,475: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.flow[f996df4e-39d3-4532-8d5c-f14de52c3280] succeeded in 233.68906934201368s: None
[2021-01-29 21:12:43,482: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.btc_yearly_candles[7227518e-06ce-41b6-b899-b10dd4bccc15]  
[2021-01-29 21:13:51,900: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Message: chrome not reachable

[2021-01-29 21:13:51,930: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.btc_wallets[0eb8e537-34b8-4512-a589-71658f91129e] succeeded in 70.32356584700756s: None
[2021-01-29 21:13:52,121: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.btc_hashrate_vs_price[2d7f3f1a-07a4-4fc4-a33c-6fe381baf9ca]
```

And that's all ... after such a log, the server froze. These were the last lines of work.

And I tried time limit on the task. I put it for 20 seconds and as soon as some task crashed with a timeout error, the rest also began to stumble over it and, as a result, timeouts and server freezes everywhere.

tasks.py

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(60.0, flow.s(), name='flow')
    sender.add_periodic_task(61.0, btc_wallets.s(), name='btc_wallets')
    sender.add_periodic_task(62.0, btc_rsi.s(), name='btc_rsi')


@app.task
def flow():
    try:
        get_screen_btc("flow")
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(err)


@app.task
def btc_wallets():
    try:
        get_screen_btc("btc_wallets")
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(err)


@app.task
def btc_rsi():
    try:
        get_screen_btc("btc_rsi")
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(err)
```

screen.py

```
def set_chrome_options() -> None:
    """Sets chrome options for Selenium.
    Chrome options for headless browser is enabled.
    """
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_prefs = {}
    chrome_options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
    chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
    return chrome_options


def get_screen_btc(chart):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=set_chrome_options())
    urls = {
        'flow': 'https://cryptoquant.com/sign-in',
        'btc_wallets': 'https://coinmarketcap.com/bitcoin-analytics/',
        'btc_rsi': 'https://digitalik.net/btc/rsi',
    }
    URL = urls[chart]
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "row"))
        )
        element.screenshot(f'{chart}.png')
   finally:
        logging.error('элемент не нашли!')
```

In the code above, I showed only three tasks, but I have about 30 of them.

Hence the question of how to solve the problem, how to curb the work of each task, regardless of the server and the village, so that the suspension of one does not affect the others and the suspended one is restarted in turn? thanks